# Jquery .each() giving me values of all elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, each

Please go to: www.designedbychristian.com/template_2

(so far being tested in chrome)

When you click design a bunch of thumbnails appear. 
I am trying to use the .each selector to get the src of the image. I want to take that value and apply it to a div that will appear when clicked. (I know how to program that part)

My problem is when I click the thumb nail my alert is giving me the value of all of the thumbnails.

my code is this:

```
    function spawnImages() {
        N = 1
        for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
            var gal = document.getElementById('gallary')

            var newDIV = '<img onclick="imageView()" src="images2/image' + N + '.jpg" class="thumb-nail imageNumber' + N + '"/>'

            $('.gallary').prepend(newDIV)
            var min = 3;
            var max = 70;
            var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            var test = $(('.imageNumber' +N)).css("left", s + "%")
            var min = 3;
            var max = $(this).height();
            var max = 70;
            var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

            var test = $(('.imageNumber' + N)).css("top", s + "%")


            var min = -45;
            var max = 45;
            var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

            var test = $(('.imageNumber' + N)).css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(" + s + "deg)")
            var test = $(('.imageNumber' + N)).css("transform", "rotate(" + s + "deg)")
            var test = $(('.imageNumber' + N)).css("-ms-transform", "rotate(" + s + "deg)")


            N++

        }
    }

    function imageView() {
        $(".thumb-nail").each(function () {
            var imageSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            alert($(this).attr('src'));
            //$('.images').css("background-image", "url("+imageSrc+")");
            //$('.images').css("background-size", "cover");
            //$('.blackForeground').css("visibility", "visible");
            //$('.images').css("visibility", "visible"); 
        })

    };
```

Comment: Uhm, well, you **are** looping over all the images and alerting the source of each and every one on every click ?

Comment: I figured that is what the problem. When i got rid of the .each and just used the alert. It came back as undefined

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest change is this

```
// send this element to the function
var newDIV = '<img onclick="imageView(this)" src="images2/image' + N + '.jpg" class="thumb-nail imageNumber' + N + '"/>'

function imageView(el) {
        var imageSrc = $(el).attr('src');
        alert($(el).attr('src'));
};
```

But it's nice to do things in a more standard fashion...

First get rid of this `onclick="imageView()"`

```
var newDIV = '<img src="images2/image' + N + '.jpg" class="thumb-nail imageNumber' + N + '"/>'
```

Since these elements are created dynamically you will need to bind the click event to document or another ancestor that exists, and delegate to each ".thumb-nail".

You also need to run this procedure only when dom is ready (`$(function(){...});`).

```
$(function(){

    $(document).on('click', ".thumb-nail", function () {
            var imageSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            alert($(this).attr('src'));
            //$('.images').css("background-image", "url("+imageSrc+")");
            //$('.images').css("background-size", "cover");
            //$('.blackForeground').css("visibility", "visible");
            //$('.images').css("visibility", "visible"); 
    });

});
```

Comment: FYI Using `.prop()` is faster than using `.attr()`

Comment: idk he/she would downvote. I wish I had enough rep to fix it. Thanks again I switched to prop as well.

Comment: S.O. should remove the downvote privilege from those who downvote without comment. You did fix it with a big green tick.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jquery event handlers, get rid of the onclick call in your html and just add this in your javascript.

```
$(".thumb-nail").on('click', function(){
            var imageSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            alert($(this).attr('src'));
            //$('.images').css("background-image", "url("+imageSrc+")");
            //$('.images').css("background-size", "cover");
            //$('.blackForeground').css("visibility", "visible");
            //$('.images').css("visibility", "visible"); 
});
```

**EDIT:** didn't think about the images being created dynamically, Popnoodles answer is the right one

Answer (score 0):

pass clicked element reference like this:

```
var newDIV = '<img onclick="imageView(this)" src="images2/image' + N + '.jpg" class="thumb-nail imageNumber' + N + '"/>'
```

Function:

```
function imageView(element) {

            var imageSrc = $(element).attr('src');
            alert($(element).attr('src'));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how the [jQuery API describes the .each() method](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

When you called `$('.thumb-nail')` it returned ALL of the elements with the class `thumb-nail` in a jQuery object. Then when you called `.each( function() {} )` on that object, the loop iterated over all of the returned elements.

The easiest way to handle click events in jQuery, is to use [the `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/), as others have pointed out in their answers.

Also, as @Popnoodles mentioned, since these elements are created dynamically, you may need to run your `$().on()` call explicitly after these elements are created. For that reason, you might wrap it into your `spawnImages()` function, rather than putting it inside `$()` as @Popnoodles indicates (i.e. not `$( $(element).on('click',function(){})`, as `$(  )` is  equivalent to `$(document).ready`.